# Software/framework in Linux for filtering HTTP traffic?

Tags: linux, open-source, http, firewall, proxy

I have been using mitmproxy for filtering HTTP traffic. mitmproxy is simple and written in Python. It will start a new thread to handle every new HTTP request.

Here are some things I need to get from those request flows:

1. URL
2. parameters
3. IP of the request
4. MAC of the request
5. **parse the content and do some logistics**

mitmdump is shipped from project mitmproxy and it works in command line. Extensively I used it in this way:

`mitmdump -T -s ./my_written_request_handler.py` (it listens on port 8000, and I used `iptables` to forward all HTTP traffic to this port)

I handled all the requests in this handler `./my_written_request_handler.py`, but I found it to be less efficient. Maybe because it's in Python!

So I want a new easy-efficient tool or framework to do this job.

Will a firewall do this job without proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I think [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) is one of your best bets if you want an efficient way to filter traffic with a lot of rules under Linux. Over the years, they say Haproxy has become "de-facto standard **opensource** load balancer, is now shipped with most mainstream Linux distributions, and is often deployed by default in cloud platforms". It's been around for quite a while and can be tricky but worth it.

From their documentation about "[What HAProxy is and is not](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/intro.html#3.1)", I can see the following that would fit your most important requirement:

HAProxy is [also] an **HTTP fixing tool**: it can modify / fix / add / remove / rewrite the **URL or any request or response header**. [...] HAProxy is [also] a **content-based switch**: it can consider any element from the request to decide what server to pass the request or connection to. [...]